# Android's equivalent to iOS's instagram://location?id=LOCATION_ID

Tags: android, instagram

I have the location_id of a location on my android app and I need to launch the Instagram app to that location.
 on iOS this was done using the iPhone Hook

```
 instagram://location?id=LOCATION_ID
```

I've been searching for two days and haven't found a way to accomplish the same on Android not even to open a browser to website instead.